# symfony Fatal error: Class 'BaseFormFilterDoctrine' not found

Tags: symfony-1.4

I encounter the following error

"symfony Fatal error: Class 'BaseFormFilterDoctrine' not found"

on php5.6 instance with old symfony 1.4 project

Answer (score 2):

as explained here : http://www.fabianfier.de/blog1.php/symfony-1-4-baseformfilterdoctrine-not-found

find file :
"/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/data/generator/sfDoctrineFormFilter/default/template/sfDoctrineFormFilterBaseTemplate.php"

and change "[" by "<"

---

**above it is a temporary solution
 : in hindsight to avoid these errors, it is best to check the project tree as defined in the literature
http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/01?orm=Doctrine#chapter_01_sub_initializing_the_project_directory**